# Qt4 files : file or directory not found

Tags: 12.04, qt, widgets

I installed qt4 and now can see its files in

```
/usr/include/qt4
```

But when I am compiling the "C" code, it gave error that

```
QWidget: file or directory not found
```

Although this QWidget is present in the path

```
/usr/include/qt4/QtGui/QWidget
```

So then I put the whole path in the file. But then it gave error that the files inside the QWidget are also unable to find, even though the files are present in the path.

Can anyone please tell me how can I solve this issue ?

For the record, I used these commands

```
sudo apt-get install libqt4-core

sudo apt-get install libqt4-dbg

sudo apt-get install libqt4-dev

sudo apt-get install libqt4-gui
```

Answer (score 0):

To compile with library, you have to install `-dev` version of this library, and `-dbg` version would not hurt too. Although, install `qt4-default` and `qt4-dev-tools`